# How do I get missing prototype warnings from g++?

Tags: c++, g++, warnings, compiler-warnings

I currently have a project that uses g++ to compile it's code.  I'm in the process of cleaning up the code, and I'd like to ensure that all functions have prototypes, to ensure things like const char * are correctly handled.  Unfortunately, g++ complains when I try to specify -Wmissing-prototypes:

```
g++ -Wmissing-prototypes -Wall -Werror -c foo.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wmissing-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
```

Can someone tell me:
  1) Why does gcc this isn't valid?  Is this a bug in gcc?
  2) Is there a way to turn on this warning?

**EDIT:**

Here's a cut and paste example:

```
cat > foo.cpp <<EOF
void myfunc(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    /* do stuff with arg1, arg2 */
}
EOF
g++ -Wmissing-prototypes -c foo.cpp  # complains about not valid
g++ -c foo.cpp                       # no warnings
# Compile in C mode, warning appears as expected:
g++ -x c -Wmissing-prototypes -c foo.cpp
```

Comment: I'm confused how that foo.cpp file should ever yield a "no prototype" warning. Your shown function definition *does* include a prototype.

Comment: May-be rather than just asking how to turn on warnings that appear to make no sense in C++ (as the warning says), you post some example what kind of error it is that you want to catch that the C++ compiler already doesn't catch ("ensuring that `const char*` are correctly handled")?

Comment: Where do you see a prototype?  The example code doesn't include a header file, and it doesn't have a separate prototype line in the foo.cpp file.

Comment: The problem I want to catch is where someone changes the definition of a function in a .cpp file, but forgets to change the header file.  With the warning, *that* developer would get an error (assuming I also have -Werror on), and he'd be able to fix it right away.  Without the warning, *some other* developer, that uses the library the first developer wrote, would get a hard to track down error while linking his program, and once he figures out what's wrong the overhead of fixing the issue is hugely increased.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try -Wmissing-declarations?  That seems to work for g++ and detect the error case you describe.  I'm not sure which version they added it in, but it works for me in 4.3.3.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I need.  Now I just need to figure out how to upgrade the version of GCC on my RHEL5 machines.

Answer (score 10):

When you compile a file with `.cpp` extension, it is compiled as C++ code by default.  In C++ language the requirement for function declarations is a mandatory, hard requirement. There's no point in making an `-Wmissing-prototypes` option for C++.

In other words, you can't "turn on this *warning*" in C++ because "missing prototype" is always an *error* in C++.

**P.S.** As a side note: The notion of *prototype* is specific to C language only. There are no "prototypes" in C++.

In C language a function *declaration* can be a *prototype* or not a prototype, hence the need for an extra term to distinguish ones from the others. In C++ function declarations are *always* "prototypes" (from C point of view), so in C++ there simply no need for this extra term. In C++ function declarations are simply *function declarations*. That just says it all.

<del>**EDIT:** After reading your comment I came to conclusion that you must have misunderstood the meaning and the purpose of the `-Wmissing-prototypes` option and corresponding warning. Note, this option will not check whether you have included prototypes of all your functions into some header file. There is no option to do that in GCC, regardless of whether you are using C or C++.</del>

The purpose of `-Wmissing-prototypes` is different. This option only works when you *call* a function that has no visible prototype at the point of the call. In C language doing this is legal, but if you'd like a warning in this case, you use `-Wmissing-prototypes` option. In C++ language calling a function that has no visible declaration ("prototype") at the point of the call is always an immediate error, which is why C++ compilers have no need for such option as `-Wmissing-prototypes`.

In other words, if you defined some function in some implementation file, but forgot to include a prototype for this function in some header file, you will not get any warnings from the compiler until you actually try to *call* that function. It doesn't matter whether your code is C or C++, whether you use `-Wmissing-prototypes` or not... Until you make an attempt to call the function, there will be no warnings.

But once you try to call a function without a prototype, the C compiler will report a warning (if you used `-Wmissing-prototypes`) and C++ compiler will always report an error.

Comment: That's not true, at least not with gcc.  It will happily compile a .cpp file that has functions without a prototype.  This means I can have foo.cpp with a function implemented as 
void myfunc(int arg1, int arg2) { /* use arg1 and arg2 */ }
but if the header file says 
void myfunc(int arg1);
then any the callers will be out of sync, and there won't be any indication of that from the compiler!

Comment: @Eric: Sorry, but what you are saying makes no sense. Firstly, in C++ the compiler *will not allow you* to call an undeclared function, period. Secondly, your example with `myfunc` is completely irrlevant. In C++ `myfunc(int, int)` and `myfunc(int)` are *two completely different* (overloaded) functions. Callers will not be "out of sync". Callers will simply call another function (assuming is defined as well). That's a matter of your intent, not a matter of "indication from the compiler". There's no error/problem in it in C++, so expecting something from the compiler would be rather strange.

Comment: If you forget to define `myfunc(int)`, then you'll get an error from linker, of course. But again, `myfunc(int)` and `myfunc(int, int)` are two completely different independent functions in C++. It is your responsibility to declare and call the right one. If you call `myfunc(int)`, the compiler will assume that that's what you wanted. If you actaully wanted to call `myfunc(int, int)` but called `myfunc(int)` by mistake... sorry, the compiler cannot read your mind to figure which one you actually *wanted* to call.

Comment: Ok, so I'd get an error from the linker.  That's better than nothing, but it makes problems harder to track down than necessary b/c the error is pointing at the wrong location, and that's assuming I even actually get to the final link stage.  
e.g.: if I'm working on a shared library, and change one of the interfaces, the problem might not show up until considerably later when I (or someone else even!) goes and tries to use the shared library to link a final program.  Instead of it being a 30 second fix because I noticed right it when compiling that file, it might take days!

Comment: @Eric: See the "EDIT" section of my answer.

Comment: err... the gcc man page clearly says "defined", not "called" for -Wmissing-prototypes: "Warn if a global function is defined without a previous prototype declaration."  Try the example I included in the question; it'll be quite clear that I'm not misunderstanding the meaning of the option.  The option that turns on warnings when *calling* a function is -Wimplicit-function-declaration (aka -Wimplicit)

Comment: @Eric: Oh, my mistake. Thanks for clearing that up for me. In that case... well, I guess the option would indeed make sense for C++ as well. Could it be that it is just spelled differently? (Since C++ doesn't normally use the term "prototype")

Comment: I think it's just not supported.  I finally found an old "closed" bug (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13687) that complains about this same problem.  I opened a new bug (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43272) with what is hopefully a more persuasive argument for allowing this warning.

Comment: @Eric: But again, the ultimate purpose of the `-Wmissing-prototypes` is to prevent the calls without the prototype. I.e. the `-Wmissing-prototypes` is related to `-Wimplicit`. The former is intended as a preventative measure, while the latter is more of an immediate per-case report. In C++ again, the whole issue of a "call without prototype" is different. You simply can't make such a call in C++, which is why `-Wmissing-prototypes` might be seen as significantly less useful in C++.

Comment: IMO, that's an argument FOR having -Wmissing-prototypes!  If you can't make a call in C++ w/o a prototype, the compiler should tell you that you're missing the prototype!  And it should do so at the moment during a build when you can actually do something about it.
In c++, -Wmissing-prototypes doesn't just prevent calls without the prototype, but it would prevent calls with the WRONG prototype.

Answer (score 8):

`-Wmissing-prototypes` is not applicable for C++, because C++ always requires prototypes.

Take the following declaration for example:

```
void foo();
```

- In C, `foo` can be called with any number and type of arguments.
- In C++, `foo` does not take any arguments (compilation error if any arguments passed in).